# Can't import 'keyboard' module even after execute 'pip3 install keyboard' and 'python3 -m pip install keyboard'

Tags: python, pip

So I am having problems with importing the Keyboard module.
I tried installing it: 
`pip3 install keyboard` and `pip install keyboard`


It still gives me the same output: 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'`
I tried solving this using the solution at:
[How to fix Error "No module named 'pynput'"? even after downloading with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623208/how-to-fix-error-no-module-named-pynput-even-after-downloading-with-pip)
I know its a different module but I thought I can use the `python -m pip install` command, but I still get the same result.

I tried checking all the module I installed using `pip freeze`, the keyboard module was there but I can't import it.


If anyone ever encountered this and has resolved this issue, please let me know.

I am using Python version 3.9.6.

Comment: Umm... What OS are you using like Mac, Windows... Cause it may also affect

Comment: I am using macOS Monterey 12.0 Beta

Comment: Hmm... I am also using a mac but not the Monterey 12.0 Beta version, did you activate the `anaconda` by typing `conda activate`

Comment: No I haven't, whats anaconda? I searched on google and it seems to be a database module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your python location and see if it's the same one as the python location in your editor.
You can check your python location by opening command prompt or any other terminal,

then type `where python` if you are in window command prompt,

`Get-Command python` in  windows powershell or

type `which python` if you are in mac, and now see in your editor if it's the same.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much. I didn't notice that VS Code defaulted to Python 2.7 for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that you have not been using Anaconda, which is essential for installing in MacOS cause of some reasons. Please go to

https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads

and install anaconda. Then follow the installation process and it should work. This is because MacOS has already `python 2.7` per-installed, so you will have to install Anaconda to use `python 3` and above. Using Anaconda, you can install any python packages without any error