# Import "pynput.keyboard" could not be resolved from source Pylance (reportMissingImports)

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, time, pynput

I am trying to write some code that essentially types a random 5 character word.
I can't get pynput.keyboard to work as I keep getting the same error message (Import "pynput.keyboard" could not be resolved from source)
my code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
keyboard = Controller()
from random import randrange
import time


alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
word = []

for i in range(5):
    x = randrange(1,26)
    #rint(x)
    l1 = alphabet[x-1]
    #print(l1)
    word.append(l1)

y = ''.join(word)
time.wait(5)
keyboard.press(y)
keyboard.release(y)
```

I already did

```
pip3 install pynput
```

My problem seems to be similar to *this* one that I found. https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/jqepj8/i_think_python_hates_me_import_pynputmouse_could/

Comment: ```python -m install pynput``` 
or
```python3 -m install pynput```

from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623208/how-to-fix-error-no-module-named-pynput-even-after-downloading-with-pip?rq=4